# After updating my project from angular 6 to 7 sometimes httpClient request goes pending

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have updated my project from `angular 6` to `angular 7` it was working fine in angular 6. When i have updated to `version 7` sometimes my `httpClient` `Get` or `Post` request is pending forever and browser tab hangs up. What can be an issue?

I am not able to always reproduce this issue.

Below is the screenshot:

[image]

`spreview` request goes in pending stage which leads to the hanging of browser.

Note:this issue persists only on development mode. When i build the project the issue doesn't persist in production (using below command).

```
ng build --prod --output-hashing none
```

Below is the post request which goes on pending in `angular 7` development and works fine in `angular 6` and after build in angular 7.

```
 getDataForPreview(formdata, bodydata) {
     return this.httpClient.post('rest/dataset/spreview', bodydata, {headers: new HttpHeaders({'id': formdata.sourceId.toString()}) });
 }
```

Comment: i am also having the same issue but didnt found the solution yet

Comment: uhm, it's a strange httpHeaders, do you want say this.httpClient.post('rest/dataset/spreview/'+formdata.sourceId.toString(), bodydata) ?

Comment: @Eliseo , No it will go in header of the request

Comment: is it an OPTIONS request? could be something wrong with your API since you its CORS

Comment: @j4rey if thats the case why other request working fine, and in angular 6 it still working fine.

Comment: could you fix this issue? I'm facing the same problem with a Post using FormData, which hangs in "Initial connection" at the chrome timing steps. Never works, it hangs forever. In dev it works fine, I can call the API and receive file binary contents.